# How to test an iMac fully before selling it?

Tags: imac, gpu, benchmark

I've owned an **2011 iMac** since that year. I really love it, but when I used to use it as my main computer, the screen would often fill up with glitchy color blocks and the computer would sometimes totally freeze.

After doing some research, someone said the **Graphics Card** was the issue. I backed it up and removed most of what was in it, and put it away.

Over the past few days, however, I've been able to use it without a problem.

*(Maybe the computer cools down when unplugged, and runs without glitches? Maybe freeing up several hundreds of Gbs made it run better? Maybe I uninstalled a background app that was draining the power of the Graphics card?)*

**I would like to know how I can fully diagnose the hardware of this computer, which is in excellent condition, before I decide to sell it or not. Via an app, a Terminal command or a Restore Boot System check if there's such a thing.**

Comment: Try the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)

Comment: @lhf would you like to write this as an answer instead? Trying it now.

Comment: @lhf I only got an error messages regarding the fans (I replaced the hard drive), which is an error I am aware of. I do not see anything regarding the failure of the gpu?

Comment: Run a GPU stress test such as this: https://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/

Comment: @anonymous I downloaded the app. Nothing happens when I click on “run stress test” and “run benchmark”.

Comment: @MicroMachine try this one: https://benchmark.unigine.com/valley

Comment: @anonymous it's pretty and relaxing, but I didn't get a good idea of whether everything in the computer runs as it should from using it